# NDK How does JNI findclass resolve to a particular instance

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My application has an imageview that is used by two different activities, the imageview was making JNI calls to retrieve data from C++. It seems to work OK which surprised me as I don't know as there are two instances of the imageview. My question is when you do a findclass and findmethodID how does JNI know what instance you are trying to callback on?

Should the JNI calls all be via the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindClass` does not resolve the instance. It finds the object that describes the class itself. Instance resolution is performed later, when you call `CallXXXMethod` - its first parameter (second in C) is an instance object.

For static methods, an instance reference is not required. That's why in JNI there's a distinct set of functions `CallStaticXXXMethod`.